# Significant figures and rounding with only exact numbers

Tags: statistics

Not 100% sure if math SE is appropriate for this, but:

If I have a computation that involves exact numbers only, say to compute the ratio $\frac{123}{157} = 0.78343949...$, where these two are from an exact count of particular objects, how many significant figures is appropriate to include in the answer, and why?

Comment: It depends on the context.  If you need exact numbers, leave it as a fraction.  If approximate answers are satisfactory, then what is error tolerance in this application.  Where are you rounding your other numbers?  If you have used  $\pi = 3.14$, and $g = 9.76$ then $3$ significant digits is sufficient.

Comment: In my particular context, no other guidelines are given.  That's the issue I'm having.  I'd agree that usually I'll just figure it out based on context.  But when it isn't given, do I just guess?

Comment: If there is no context it is safest to assume that you need to be exact. In which case you would leave it as a fraction.

Comment: I would leave it as a fraction, unless I had other context that made me think a decimal would be more friendly.  And then I would use that context to guide me.

Comment: Fair points.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the answer depends a lot on the context you need to report the solution in.

If it is an assignment or test, 2 or 4 significant digits are usually enough.

If you are using this number in further calculations, the best practice would be keep it as a ratio for as many steps as possible. In the final step, compute the decimal value as required.

Comment: I agree on what is usually considered to be "enough", for sure.  It does depend on context.  My question was more so - what are the rules governing this if context is not available?  Or, more fundamentally, do such rules even exist?

Comment: In light of the above comments, this answer is great.  Thanks

Comment: I have not come across rules. One usually is trying to make a point when reporting a number (e.g, A/B = 3.16, which is greater than $\pi$). Devoid of even this context, in situations where you are *required* to write as decimals, I stand by my answer of 2 or 4 significant digits. It strikes a balance between detail and aesthetics/space taken up and I don't see an argument for greater precision. 

You're welcome, and thanks to you too!